# Top Rated Products do_shortcode in php not working when attributes added

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

When I add this code:

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode("[top_rated_products orderby="rand" per_page="15"]");
?>
```

to my php page, it doesn't work, but it works when I use this:

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode("[top_rated_products ]");
?>
```

Is there any way to allow for the first code to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the shortcode in single quotes like

```
do_shortcode('[top_rated_products orderby="rand" per_page="15"]');
```